# Naming 'ArrayOf' when serialising using DataContractSerializer

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service that has multiple operation contracts defined. One of my contracts returns a collection of known types. The type is defined separately as a data contract.

When the collection is serialised by the **DataContractSerializer** the xml representation defines the name of the collection as

```
<ArrayOfMyType*></ArrayOfMyType>
```

I want to alter this to return it as

```
<MyTypes></MyTypes>
```

but can seem to find the required attribute within the documentation. I have used XmlRootAttribute in another part of the system but that is designed for the XMLSerialiser

Answer (score 4):

Try to define custom collection type:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "MyTypes", ItemName = "MyType")]
public class MyTypeList : List<MyType>
{ }
```

And use this type as return value from your operation.

Comment: Seems weird that I can't simply define the name for collection as it's being serialised as I do when using the XMLSerialiser. But then I guess I'm not manually invoking it so there's no chance to. Thanks